# How to save and print selected result from multiple mysql tables in one array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays

I need to get post_id count from six table but i can not do it with using UNION in one query
A query is prepared successfuly but when i need to display result it's not working
could someone explain what's wrong and how to solve problem?

```
$query = "(SELECT COUNT(post_id) as realestate_count FROM realestate)
          UNION
          (SELECT COUNT(post_id) as cars_count FROM cars)
          UNION
          (SELECT COUNT(post_id) as spectechnic_count FROM spectechnic)
          UNION
          (SELECT COUNT(post_id) as motorcycles_count FROM motorcycles)
          UNION
          (SELECT COUNT(post_id) as parts_count FROM parts)
          UNION
          (SELECT COUNT(post_id) as beauty_count FROM beauty)";

$stmt   = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$result = $result->fetch_assoc();

print_r($result["realestate_count"]); // got undefined array key error with all
print_r($result["cars_count"]);
print_r($result["spectechnic_count"]);
print_r($result["motorcycles_count"]);
print_r($result["parts_count"]);
print_r($result["beauty_count"]);
```

Comment: Your result will only have one column named realestate_count.

Comment: I got undefined array key error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use subqueries instead of union to get what you want.

```
  SELECT COUNT(post_id)  as realestate_count ,
  (SELECT COUNT(post_id) FROM cars) as cars_count,
  (SELECT COUNT(post_id) FROM spectechnic)as spectechnic_count ,
  (SELECT COUNT(post_id) FROM motorcycles)as motorcycles_count,          
  (SELECT COUNT(post_id) FROM parts)      as parts_count,
  (SELECT COUNT(post_id) FROM beauty)     as beauty_count 
  FROM realestate
```